# Can't plot my equation!

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the following equation,
[image]

But for some reason PGFPlots doesn't seem to work???? This is the code im inputing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-10, ymax=10]
     \addplot[domain=-10:10]{(x*x+x-6)/(x*x-3*x-10)};
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the error message I'm getting in Overleaf
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should mention the domain explicitly to show up to what values of x you want to plot for. Try `\addplot expression[domain=-10:10]{x*x+x-6/x*x-3*x-10};`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but the error persists even after expliciting the domain :c

Comment: What kind of error? It looks fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to define (large enough) number of samples, for example `samples=300`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     grid,
      xmin=-10, xmax=10, 
      ymin=-10, ymax=10,
      samples=300
            ]
\addplot[domain=-10:10]{(x*x+x-6)/(x*x-3*x-10)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMG THAT WORKED! tysm I'm just a high-school senior who learned how to use latex yesterday so I'm glad to know how to do this now, <3, do you know by any chance how to delete the lines at x=-2 and x=5? Since they shouldnt actually be there lol

Comment: Those lines basically mean the function is undefined at those values of x.

Comment: Is there any way to remove them, or change the style so they don't look like the function itself?

Comment: @GregorioSamsa: yes, there is a way. One way can define sampling points where you skip samples where function is not defined. For more I need to read package documentation again :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution without the vertical lines. They are drawn, simply because two valid points are connected (as they are for the rest of the plot/graph). To avoid this you need to calculate points on the undefined points, i.e. `-2` and `+5`. Since these are integers this is quite easy to do when the `domain` ends are also integers. For `domain=-10:10` this can be achieved with a minimum number of samples of `21`, i.e. `samples=21` where at every integer is one sample.

But of course with this low number of samples the poles are not visualized very well. So increase it until you are satisfied.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        xmin=-10, xmax=10,
        ymin=-10, ymax=10,
        % add this option to show a gap for non-valid points (i.e. `inf` and `NaN`)
        unbounded coords=jump,
        domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},
        samples=401,
        no markers,
    ]
        \addplot+ [thick] {(x*x+x-6)/(x*x-3*x-10)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks! I've already resolved that problem with ```restrict y to domain=[ymin]:[ymax]```, but this one is more straight forward! appreciate your help