# tangens function pgfplots detail

Tags: pgfplots

I read the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521359/14423 for draw a a function based on the tangent function but I have an issue with asymptotes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-4*pi:2*pi,xmin=-13,
    xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=15,
    trig format plots=rad,
    %samples=100,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xtick={-4*pi,-3*pi,-2*pi,-pi,pi,2*pi},
    xticklabels={$-4\pi$,$-3\pi$, $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$},
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    legend style={at={(1.45,.9)}}]%legend pos=north east] 
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-5,-3,...,1}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{ifthenelse(#1==-5,-4*pi,#1*pi-0.01)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{ifthenelse(#1==1,2*pi,#1*pi+2*pi+0.01)}
\addplot[samples=51,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax]{-0.5*tan(x/2)-x};
\draw[densely dotted] (#1*pi,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
 -- (#1*pi,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Appears a filled lines next to the dotted lines in asymtotes, but I don't know what makes that. Increase samples don't fix it. How to fix it?

Comment: I saw a similar problem recently but I do not find it atm. I guess that you need to define a reasonable `samples at` option that does exclude the poles. See also in your linked answer: *"Therefore, I'd rather plot the branches separately in a loop, and thus avoid the poles."*

Comment: I found the question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602730. I will mark it as a possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.ManuelKuehner for response but this have some problems, with `samples=250` the filled lines hides the dotted line. With `samples=300` I got error message: `Dimension too large`

Comment: `samples at` (or `domain`) is different from `samples`. A comment also suggests `restrict y to domain=[ymin]:[ymax]`.

Comment: Well I can't find `samples at` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/602730/14423 , sorry

Comment: I do not have time at the moment to be of more support. But I recommend that you simplify your plot for just one period and play with that. When you understand it then you try the complex version.,

Comment: Sorry but your new suggestion makes no difference, the problem still there.

Comment: As I said, I am too busy right now. But I posted a simplified version. Maybe it helps. If not then I am sorry :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the code in my post I noticed that I made a mistake while I was conforming the intervals. The solution was change `+0.01` by `-0.01` and vice versa, in `\xmin` and `\mxax`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-4*pi:2*pi,xmin=-13,
    xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=15,
    trig format plots=rad,
    %samples=100,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xtick={-4*pi,-3*pi,-2*pi,-pi,pi,2*pi},
    xticklabels={$-4\pi$,$-3\pi$, $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$},
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    legend style={at={(1.45,.9)}}]%legend pos=north east] 
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-5,-3,...,1}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{ifthenelse(#1==-5,-4*pi,#1*pi+0.01)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{ifthenelse(#1==1,2*pi,#1*pi+2*pi-0.01)}
 \addplot[samples=250,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax]{-0.5*tan(x/2)-x};
 \draw[densely dotted] (#1*pi,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
  -- (#1*pi,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
  }

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is related to my comment regarding `domain` (or `samples at`) that should exclude the poles.

Comment: Not necessarily. The change was in the definition of \ xmin and \ xmax with sign of `0.01` and increasing `samples`. In any case I appreciate your time and interest. Helped me correct myself

Comment: Yes, but `xmax` and `xmin` is then used within `\addplot[samples=250,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax]{-0.5*tan(x/2)-x};` (the `domain=\xmin:\xmax` part is relevant). Anyway, happy that the problem got solved. I am currently working on a Udacity course and should not procrastinate so much :).

Comment: I'm not sure that `xmin` and `xmax` are related with `\xmin` and `\xmax`, respectively. I'm not a pro with `pgfplots`.

Comment: I mean `\xmin` and *not* `xmin`, my mistake.

Comment: Regards Mr Kuehner and thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

See [Stefan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602730) for an explanation of the problem.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    grid,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-7,
    xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5,
    trig format plots=rad,
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602730 (comment)
    restrict y to domain=-5:5, % <-- Added
    ]
    \addplot[samples=501, no markers, smooth, domain=-2*pi:2*pi, red]{tan(x)};
    \addplot[samples=501, no markers, smooth, domain=-2*pi:2*pi, blue]{-0.5*tan(x/2)-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing yor response I notice that problem appears when I draw the dotted lines.

Answer (score 2):

like this:

[image]

Similar to @Dr. Manuel Kuehner's answer (he beat me for few minutes, +1):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-13,   xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,    ymax=15,
    restrict y to domain=-20:30,                % <---
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    xlabel=$x$,
    xtick={-4*pi, -3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, pi, 2*pi},
    xticklabels={$-4\pi$, $-3\pi$, $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$},
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.05)}, anchor=north, font=\scriptsize},
    trig format plots=rad,
    domain=-4*pi:2*pi, samples=1001, no marks   % <---
            ]%legend pos=north east]
\addplot +[thick]{-0.5*tan(x/2)-x};
\legend{$-0.5\tan(x/2)-x$}
%
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-5,-3,...,1}%
{
\draw[densely dotted] (#1*pi,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
 -- (#1*pi,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** corrected used function. Above solution work with it too.

Comment: +1: Nice! I am going offline now.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thank you very much, and thank you for edit. Here is (very) early morning and I'm not completely wakeup yet ;-)

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly.

Comment: Well in my case the function is `-0.5*tan(x/2)-x` and I got error ...

Comment: @juanuni, it works. See edited answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, this works, I think I made a mistake copyng the code. Thanks.